# Dragged component does change the position after drop

Tags: java, vaadin

I tried to drag a button and drop it another layout in my vaadin ui. But it does not work. It does not change position to where I drop it. Below is my code. Any help is great.

```
public class TestDrag extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {

        setSizeFull();
        addStyleName("stores");


        HorizontalLayout layout1=new HorizontalLayout();
        Button button=new Button("Save");
        DragAndDropWrapper draggable = new DragAndDropWrapper(button);
        draggable.setDragStartMode(DragStartMode.COMPONENT);
        draggable.setSizeFull();
        layout1.addComponent(draggable); // add it to some layout
        addComponent(layout1);


        HorizontalLayout layout2=new HorizontalLayout();
        layout2.setSizeFull();
        Button button1=new Button("Cancel");
        layout2.addComponent(button1);

        DragAndDropWrapper destiny = new DragAndDropWrapper(
                layout2);
        addComponent(destiny);
        destiny.setDropHandler(new DropHandler() {

            @Override
            public AcceptCriterion getAcceptCriterion() {
              return AcceptAll.get();
            }

            @Override
            public void drop(DragAndDropEvent event) {
              Notification.show("Dropped!");

            }
          });
        destiny.setSizeFull();
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the way to do it and I just had to change the drop method as below

```
        @Override
        public void drop(DragAndDropEvent event) {
          Notification.show("Dropped!");
          WrapperTransferable t = (WrapperTransferable) event.getTransferable();
          layout2.addComponent(t.getSourceComponent());
        }
```